# Comparing many images with one

Tags: java, image, algorithm, image-processing

I need to compare many images in database with one and mark it if their equals. I have two ideas for solve this problem:

1. Get hash of both images (MD5) and compare their hashes. This method allows calculate etalon image's hash only one time.
2. Compare all images with etalon pixel-to-pixel.

What method will be faster? Comparing all pixels or calculate hash for all images in database?

Comment: "Get hash of both images (MD5) and compare their hashes". You will still need to compare the actual images. Hashes have collisions.

Comment: what do you mean by *compare*? Looking for *similarity* or *equal/not equal*?

Comment: equal/not equal

Comment: What's an "etalon"?

Comment: I'd recommend running through on paper what will happen in each case for a few examples. That should make the performance difference between them pretty clear. Or write the code for both and benchmark. Although the implementation details could make a huge difference in the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply depends how often you want to compare an image with the DB.

If you only need to do this once or twice, go for pixel-to-pixel compare.
because to create all the hash-values you need also to read all pixels of all images once.

If you often need to do this, go for the hash approach. Of cause you need to compare the images with same hash-value pixel by pixel, but that are far less than all images. (You might even be able to keep all hash-values in RAM, if your DB is not too big)

You do not need to use md5. You could even go for far simpler (and faster to calculate) hash functions. (You do not need the features needed for cryptographic hash-functions like md5 (even if md5 is not secure anymore)).
You simply want to reduce the number of images to compare pixel by pixel.